# Select row by latest datetime

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, datetime

I have the following view, which is pulling rows from the raw tables that PERFMON creates. A new row is inserted every 60 seconds.

```
SELECT        
    dbo.CounterDetails.MachineName, dbo.CounterDetails.ObjectName, 
    dbo.CounterDetails.CounterName, dbo.CounterDetails.InstanceName, 
    dbo.CounterData.CounterValue, CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR(16), 
    dbo.CounterData.CounterDateTime)) AS Date, dbo.CounterData.GUID
FROM            
    dbo.CounterData 
INNER JOIN
    dbo.CounterDetails ON dbo.CounterData.CounterID = dbo.CounterDetails.CounterID 
INNER JOIN
    dbo.DisplayToID ON dbo.CounterData.GUID = dbo.DisplayToID.GUID
```

Where a select * would return, e.g.

```
    GUID    CounterID   RecordIndex CounterDateTime CounterValue    FirstValueA FirstValueB SecondValueA    SecondValueB    MultiCount
    362035A1-50A6-4F91-9423-82DCB5DED11B    1   1   2014-11-20 12:35:30.635 7459    7459    0   0   0   1
...
...
...

    GUID    CounterID   RecordIndex CounterDateTime CounterValue    FirstValueA FirstValueB SecondValueA    SecondValueB    MultiCount
    362035A1-50A6-4F91-9423-82DCB5DED11B    115 283 2014-11-20 17:22:13.424 0   0   0   0   0   1
```

I'm trying to get the most recent row from the view based on the `DATE` value (DateTime) for a web-based application where I only want to display the most recent (last) row in the view. I've tried a lot of things, here's the latest, everything I've tried gives me all rows. It is even possible to restrict a query to last inserted row by time (or even more complex, look for ANY time stamp that is less than 60 seconds old at execution time).

```
SELECT 
    CounterValue , MachineName, ObjectName, CounterName,[Date]
FROM 
    [dbo].[PerfView] A
WHERE 
    ObjectName = 'Network Interface' 
    AND CounterName = 'Bytes Total/sec' 
    AND CounterValue <> 0 
    AND MachineName = '\\******** 
    AND [Date] = (SELECT MAX([Date]) 
                  FROM [dbo].[PerfView] B 
                  WHERE a.CounterValue = b.CounterValue)
```

Comment: `select top 1 ... order by [date] desc`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will give you the newest record:

```
SELECT top 1 CounterValue , MachineName, ObjectName, CounterName,[Date]
 FROM [dbo].[PerfView] A
 Where ObjectName = 'Network Interface' 
 and CounterName = 'Bytes Total/sec' 
 and CounterValue <>0 
 and MachineName = '\\******** 
order by [date] desc
```

If you want the record in the last 60 seconds try:

```
SELECT CounterValue , MachineName, ObjectName, CounterName,[Date]
 FROM [dbo].[PerfView] A
 Where ObjectName = 'Network Interface' 
 and CounterName = 'Bytes Total/sec' 
 and CounterValue <>0 
 and MachineName = '\\******** 
 and [date] between dateadd(minute, -1, getdate()) and getdate()
```

Comment: Was waiting when you come up with the answer :).

Comment: @Rahul thanks for waiting. :)  So close to 10K I can taste it!

Comment: That's obvious, why should I post it as answer, you should. Anyways go little more closer :).

Comment: I went with @paqogomez, the first solution. his second one, while it works if there is one instance of machinename in the results, doesn't work if there are multiple machine names in the results (e.g. the last value for 6 machines is returned). This is querying a perfmon dump, and due to the intricacies of explaining to a datacenter administrator what a time server is (like explaining rocket science to a 2 year old), I am unfortunately able to get all of the servers synced to the same time. Thus, if I want the last value for 6 machines, if I use "last minute", I'll only get 3 of them.

Answer (score 0):

@tpcolson,

There may be many ways to go for that.
One way is what @paqogomez has suggested. That will give you what you are looking for.
Another way is to use rowcount.
Do Set RowCount 1 and then run the query without top 1. It will also give you the same result.

Another way is applicable if you are using sql server 2012. There is a offset fetch clause.
After order by use:

```
offset 0 rows fetch next 1 rows only
```

Hope it will help you.